# JavaScript this.checked

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, if we write the following for example:

```
var c = this.checked;
```

What is `checked` here? Is it just a **state** that tells us if a checkbox for example is checked or *not*? So, can we use it to check that the checkbox is also not checked?

Comment: Non of the answers give the solution from the javascript (not from jquery)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it just a state that tells us if a checkbox for example is checked or not? So, can we use it to check that the checkbox is also not checked?

Yes and yes

Answer (score 41):

To use the pseudo selector `:checked` with the jquery object `this` write:

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

Comment: I don't see jQuery among the tags of this question... `document.getElementById("example").checked` suggested by James Allardice below works fine without having to include the entire jQuery library though

Answer (score 11):

Assuming `this` refers to a DOM element which has a `checked` property (e.g. a checkbox or a radio button) then the `checked` property will either be `true` if the element is checked, or `false` if it's not. For example, given this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="example">
```

The following line of JS will return `false`:

```
var c = document.getElementById("example").checked; //False
```

Note that what you've written is standard JavaScript, not jQuery. If `this` refers to a jQuery object rather than a DOM element, `checked` will be undefined because the jQuery object does not have a `checked` property. If `this` is a jQuery object, you can use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
var c = this.prop("checked");
```

Answer (score 5):

[In jQuery checked is a selector:](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

> The :checked selector works for checkboxes and radio buttons.

There are some ways to check if a checkbox is checked or not:

**For Example:**

```
$('#checkBox').attr('checked'); 

or 

$('#checkBox').is(':checked');
```