# is(':checked')/this.checked not working

Tags: input, checked

Tried several solutions before posting, but none seems to be working and I must be doing something wrong.

My code is as follows (simplified)

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-image-settings-container" value="1" name="..." checked="checked">
    Add image?
</label>

<div class="image-settings">show content if checked</div>
```

js code

```
$( ".image-settings" ).hide();

var wrapper = $(this).closest('li.menu-item');      

if ( $('input#menu-image-settings-container').is(':checked') ) {
    wrapper.find('.image-settings').show();
    console.log('is-checked');
} else {
    wrapper.find('.image-settings').hide();
    console.log('is-not-checked');
}


$('input#menu-image-settings-container').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        wrapper.find('.image-settings').show();
    } else {
        wrapper.find('.image-settings').hide();
    }
});
```

`console.log` says `is-not-checked`, while it clearly is in the source code.
I've tried using `if ($('input#menu-image-settings-container').is(':checked')) {...}` but that didn't worked either, while normally that should work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, is(':checked') is a correct solution. Here's why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7672031/9145243
And you can see that in this part of code your console.log works.

The actual problem is in this construction: `wrapper.find('.image-settings').hide();` This code just can't find your `.image-settings` element.

I've replaced it with `$('.image-settings')` just to show you that the problem was here.

```
$('input#menu-image-settings-container').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.image-settings').show();
    } else {
        $('.image-settings').hide();
    }
});
```

When you debug your code it's a good practise to always use console.log, line by line. And then you will clearly see where exactly you have a problem

Comment: Thank you; got it working after following your advice about console.log.